# Switching sound card without restarting the browser

Tags: firefox, alsa, iceweasel

Does anyone know if Iceweasel (Firefox) runs HTML5 audio/video in a separate process that can be restarted? With Flash I can restart `plugin-container` after changing the sound card in `~/.asoundrc`. With HTML5 audio/video it seems like I need to restart the whole browser, which at times can be a bit inconvenient.

Comment: I think this is a bug in Firefox, see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1278593

Comment: chrome has same problem